# Basic HTAccess 301 Redirect Not a rule redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect a ton of .html pages to a specific page of similar content (now managed with Wordpress).

So:

http://domain.com/page.html  =>   301 redirects too  =>   http://domain.com/page/

I need the 301 redirect to work even if the page.html file still exists in it's same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this really easily with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)[.]html$ /$1/ [L,redirect=permanent]
```

---

If you'd rather do it one-by-one, you can use the [Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) instead.

Comment: I don't want a ReWrite Rule, how do I do it for a specific page

Comment: Oh yeah Redirect worked great, I just realized some of the URL's I need to redirect are like this: /home.php?cat=274 when I tried a Redirect with a PHP Query like that it doesn't work, but it does work with regular HTML files.

Comment: I found I can do this on the home.php page itself and get the Category ID to know which Redirect to do, I hope that's good enough for google.